# Many2many as 'composition' of two One2many

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Suppose I have three objects **A, B, C** with relationships one **A** to many **B** and one **A** to many **C**. This naturally implies the existence of a many **B** to many **C** relationship, but the implication is clearly not recognized by the computer.

The questions are,

(i) How can this many2many be defined so that it respects the links as given through the already existing relationships?

(ii) Are there any special means of displaying said relationship in the form-view for each of objects **B** and **C**?

(iii) Is it possible that this is inherently the meaning of a many2many relationship and that I should just browse through the plethora of non-existent examples in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define a related `fields.Many2many` that uses relationships from **B** to **C**. See: [Related Fields Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields)

For example:

```
Model_A:
    b_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='B',
                            inverse_name='a_id')
    c_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='C',
                            inverse_name='a_id')
Model_B:
    a_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='A')
    c_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='C',
                             related='a_id.c_ids')
Model_C:
    a_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='A')
    b_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='B',
                             related='a_id.b_ids')
```

Once you've defined the related fields, all the normal Many2many interactions will work (views, ORM, etc).  You can add `store=True` to the field definition to store the relation in its own database table for easier searching and queries.